# Passing API call results to trigger render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-three-fiber

I am fairly new to react and am stuck on how i pass the results of my api call to another component file to then trigger a render. Can anyone give me a simple explanation of what I need to to please?

this is my code that calls to the API and then i need the weatherDescription state to be used in and IF statement to conditionally render a local GLTF file to the canvas

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "dotenv";

export default function WeatherLogic() {
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState("");
  const [temperature, setTemp] = useState("");
  const [weatherDescript, setWeatherDescript] = useState("");

  const handleInput = (event) => {
      setUserLocation(event.target.value);
  };

  const getWeather = async (userLocation) => {
      const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY;
      const res = await fetch(
          `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${userLocation}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`
      );
      const data = await res.json();

      setTemp(data.main.temp);
 
      setWeatherDescript(data.weather[0].description);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
       getWeather(userLocation);
  }, [userLocation]);

  return (
     <div className="formcontainerparent">
       <div className="formcontainerchild">
         <form className="weatherform">
           <label>Location
             <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={userLocation}
                onChange={handleInput}
             />
           </label>
         </form>
         <h1>{userLocation}</h1>
         <h2>{temperature}°C</h2>
         <h3>{weatherDescript}</h3>
       </div>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches will be to make a state for local GLTF file like:

```
const [file,setFile] = useState(null)
```

then make another useEffect hook and set this file on discription changes, i.e, add weatherDescript in it's dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(condition) 
    setFile(...datawhichyouneedtorender)
 }, [weatherDescript]);
```

And lastly, in your jsx render the file variable in convas.